# Заполнение таблицы из другой таблицы SQL

Tags: sql

Ребят, не могу разобраться как составить запрос INSERT

Есть таблица

```
Table1
    ID_Table1
    ID_Tovar
    ID_Obratv
    Kolizesvto
```

И вторая таблица

```
Table2
   ID_Table2
   ID_Tovar
   ID_Obratv
   Kolizestvo_racxod
```

Как заполнить первую таблицу из данных второй? И когда увеличивается  ID_Obratv, то получение  поля `Kolizesvto = Kolizestvo_racxod(Table2) + Kolizesvto(Table1) где ID_Obratv - 1`

Comment: Это называется "сумма с накоплением", ежели чё... ну да ладно. *Как заполнить первую таблицу из данных второй?* Поскольку в исходной (второй) таблице в принципе нет данных, устанавливающих порядок записей, данные неоднозначны, а задача нерешаема.

Comment: А что можно тут придумать? Есть данные всех товаров с нулевыми значениями

Comment: В структуре КАЖДОЙ таблицы обязано существовать поле штампа времени.

Comment: @Akina,  таблица Obratv имеет дату времени. Тут они связаны полем  ID_Obratv

Comment: Ну так и показывайте CREATE TABLE этих таблиц, а "не сочинение по мотивам"... ну и пример исходного заполнения плюс желаемый на таких данных результат - тоже полезно.